# How to deploy Angular front end only application to AWS (S3 or any other) generated using Jhipster?

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, deployment, jhipster, client-side

I have generated application code separately for front end (Angular) and back end (JAVA) using **Jhipster**. I know how to deploy JAVA to AWS, but I am not sure about Angular application. For a normal angular app, I would build using ng build --prod and upload all the files in dist folder in AWS s3. But with this jhipster generated angular only app, I am not sure how to do a deployment? Could you please suggest a way to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution. To get the files, we need to run **npm run build** or **npm run webpack:prod**. All the necessary files will be available under **/build/resources/main/static/** folder. Then upload the files to S3 as we usually do for normal angular app.

Comment: Im trying to separete the front and the backend but I cant et fronapp load port 9000  or 4200